# Add odd class to odd li's within 'sub-menu' ul's using custom walker

Tags: wordpress, function, navigation, submenu

I'm currently using a custom walker for my WP menu in WordPress but I just need 1 final amendment. I need to know how to...

**Give an 'odd' class to all odd li's within all 'sub-menu' ul's.
So that's the first 'sub-menu' after a parent, and all 'sub-menu' ul's within it.**

Here's the custom walker I'm currently using so if you could edit this that would be awesome!

```
class Menu_With_Description extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{

    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"sub-menu level-".$depth."\">\n";
    }
    function end_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent<div class=\"fix\"></div></ul><div class=\"fix\"></div>\n";
    }

/**
 * Start the element output.
 *
 * @param  string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
 * @param  object $item   Menu item data object.
 * @param  int $depth     Depth of menu item. May be used for padding.
 * @param  array $args    Additional strings.
 * @return void
 */
 function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth=0, $args, &$output )
{
$id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];
if ( is_object( $args[0] ) ) {
    $args[0]->has_children = ! empty( $children_elements[$element->$id_field] );
}
return parent::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
}

function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args)
{

    $classes     = empty ( $item->classes ) ? array () : (array) $item->classes;

    $class_names = join(
        ' '
    ,   apply_filters(
            'nav_menu_css_class'
        ,   array_filter( $classes ), $item
        )
    );

    if ($args->has_children && $depth == 0){
    ! empty ( $class_names )
        and $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) . ' has_children"';
    }else{
     ! empty ( $class_names )
        and $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';
    }

    $output .= "<li id='menu-item-$item->ID' $class_names>" ;
    $attributes  = '';

    ! empty( $item->attr_title )
        and $attributes .= ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"';
    ! empty( $item->target )
        and $attributes .= ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"';
    ! empty( $item->xfn )
        and $attributes .= ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"';
    ! empty( $item->url )
        and $attributes .= ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"';

    // insert description for top level elements only
    // you may change this
    $description = ( ! empty ( $item->description ) and 0 == $depth )
        ? '<span class="description">' . esc_attr( $item->description ) . '</span>' : '';

    $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );
if ( $depth == 0 ) {//top level items
        $item_output = $args->before
        ."<div class='parent'><div class='cat-icon'></div><div class='title-desc'>"
        . "<a $attributes>"
        . $args->link_before
        . $title
        . '</a><br>'
        . $args->link_after
        . $description
        . '</div></div>'
        . $args->after;
    }else{//everything else
    $item_output = $args->before
        . "<a $attributes>"
        . $args->link_before
        . $title
        . '</a> '
        . $args->link_after
        . $args->after;
    }
    // Since $output is called by reference we don't need to return anything.
    $output .= apply_filters(
        'walker_nav_menu_start_el'
    ,   $item_output
    ,   $item
    ,   $depth
    ,   $args
    );
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's my fast solution to your problem (but maybe someone find simpler one):

1. Define protected/private variable for your walker class. This is an array with current items counters on every depth level. Because start_lvl method isn't called before first item of 0 level, you have to fill 0 index of your array by 0 value.

   ```
   protected $_itemsNoByDepth = array( 0 => 0 );
   ```
2. When you start next level you have to set level counter to 0 in start_lvl method. Because first sub-level have $depth value 0 you have add 1 to this value.

   ```
   $this->_itemsNoByDepth[$depth+1] = 0;
   ```
3. Finally you have to iterate proper counter in every occurrence of start_el method. After it you can use this counter to add required classes as a new $classes array indexes. In your case it will be:

   ```
   $this->_itemsNoByDepth[$depth]++;
   if( $depth > 0 && $this->_itemsNoByDepth[$depth] % 2 ) {
    $classes[] = 'odd';
   }
   ```

   but if you'd like to add eg. odd/even classes and classes with consecutive items numbers, you can do sth like:

   ```
   $this->_itemsNoByDepth[$depth]++;
   $classes[] = 'item-no-' . $this->_itemsNoByDepth[$depth];
   $classes[] = 'item-' . ( $this->_itemsNoByDepth[$depth] % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even' );
   ```

   Remember to put above code between $classes and $class_names variable declarations.

After these three steps your code should looks like that:

```
class Menu_With_Description extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{

    protected $_itemsNoByDepth = array( 0 => 0 );

    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
        $this->_itemsNoByDepth[$depth+1] = 0;
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"sub-menu level-".$depth."\">\n";
    }
    function end_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent<div class=\"fix\"></div></ul><div class=\"fix\"></div>\n";
    }

/**
 * Start the element output.
 *
 * @param  string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
 * @param  object $item   Menu item data object.
 * @param  int $depth     Depth of menu item. May be used for padding.
 * @param  array $args    Additional strings.
 * @return void
 */
 function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth=0, $args, &$output )
{
$id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];
if ( is_object( $args[0] ) ) {
    $args[0]->has_children = ! empty( $children_elements[$element->$id_field] );
}
return parent::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
}

function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args)
{

    $classes     = empty ( $item->classes ) ? array () : (array) $item->classes;

    $this->_itemsNoByDepth[$depth]++;
    if( $depth > 0 && $this->_itemsNoByDepth[$depth] % 2 ) {
        $classes[] = 'odd';
    }

    $class_names = join(
        ' '
    ,   apply_filters(
            'nav_menu_css_class'
        ,   array_filter( $classes ), $item
        )
    );

    if ($args->has_children && $depth == 0){
    ! empty ( $class_names )
        and $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) . ' has_children"';
    }else{
     ! empty ( $class_names )
        and $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';
    }

    $output .= "<li id='menu-item-$item->ID' $class_names>" ;
    $attributes  = '';

    ! empty( $item->attr_title )
        and $attributes .= ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"';
    ! empty( $item->target )
        and $attributes .= ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"';
    ! empty( $item->xfn )
        and $attributes .= ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"';
    ! empty( $item->url )
        and $attributes .= ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"';

    // insert description for top level elements only
    // you may change this
    $description = ( ! empty ( $item->description ) and 0 == $depth )
        ? '<span class="description">' . esc_attr( $item->description ) . '</span>' : '';

    $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );
if ( $depth == 0 ) {//top level items
        $item_output = $args->before
        ."<div class='parent'><div class='cat-icon'></div><div class='title-desc'>"
        . "<a $attributes>"
        . $args->link_before
        . $title
        . '</a><br>'
        . $args->link_after
        . $description
        . '</div></div>'
        . $args->after;
    }else{//everything else
    $item_output = $args->before
        . "<a $attributes>"
        . $args->link_before
        . $title
        . '</a> '
        . $args->link_after
        . $args->after;
    }
    // Since $output is called by reference we don't need to return anything.
    $output .= apply_filters(
        'walker_nav_menu_start_el'
    ,   $item_output
    ,   $item
    ,   $depth
    ,   $args
    );
}

}
```

Comment: Perfect! I wanted to vote it up but I don't have enough reputation :( Thanks though bud.